# TSQL syntax - Is aliasing with a quoted prefix depricated?

Tags: t-sql

Can anyone tell me if writing a query in the following tsql syntax is either (1) currently -- or going to be soon -- deprecated by MSFT, or (2) in opposition to some best practice of which I'm not aware?

```
SELECT 
'CustName' = (SELECT Lastname + ', ' + Firstname FROM Cust WHERE CustID = O.CustID),
'ProdName' = (SELECT ProductName FROM Product WHERE ProductID = O.ProductID)
FROM Orders O
```

The specific question is putting the new column name all the way to the "front" or left of the line as opposed to writing the subquery and putting the new column name in square brackets after the subquery. Obviously both will work, but the DBAs reviewing my database code typically give me a WTF look when they see this, even though I tell them it's far more readable because all of your column names are on the left...

Is there something wrong with writing queries in this manner?

**CLARIFICATION:** The point isn't the subqueries in the SELECT statement, it's whether the syntax:

```
'NewColumnName' = OldColumnName
```

is going away anytime soon. I chose to demonstrate the question with a pair of subqueries rather than using the giant and esoteric custom function calls and case statements that are actually in the production code I'm using.

Comment: Is the WTF from the naming convention or the subqueries in the select clause?

Comment: From putting the new column name at the front of the line instead of at the end of the line in square brackets. I don't usually use subqueries in the manner shown... just a quick example of a renaming structure...

Comment: And for the record, there is nothing wrong with writing sub-queries the way that you have them written there. As long as you are not duplicating table references in them the optimizer in 2005 and above turns them into join equivalents anyway.

Comment: What's the point of the single quotes, anyway?  I use colName = <sql expression> all the time.  I much prefer it to AS colName but never with single quotes.

Comment: RBarryYoung, that is a correlated subquery and even in SQL Server 2008, it will be signicantly slower as it must evaluate record by record rather than in a set-fashion. Write up a sample both ways and check the execution plan, you will see. Correlated subqueries should virtually never be used instead of a join (it may sometimes need to be a join to a derived table) espcially on production.

Comment: This is not true, it used to be true in SQL 2000, but it was almost entirely fixed by 2005. I have done it both ways many times, if they are logically equivalent to begin with the compiler will usually produce the same or equivalent plan.  I am happy to provide examples.  (I have occaisionally even seen the reverse, where the subqueries actually had faster plans)

Comment: I was not aware of that syntax, but I like it. I'll be using it in the future.

Comment: Example where subqueries have faster plans here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007418/sql-server-2005-error-when-grouping-using-subquery - see the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to SQL 2005 BOL here (ms-help://MS.SQLCC.v9/MS.SQLSVR.v9.en/instsql9/html/c10eeaa5-3d3c-49b4-a4bd-5dc4fb190142.htm) and here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729(SQL.90).aspx and in the 2008 doc here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx (look under "Transact-SQL" features) this will be deprecated in a future release (unspecified).

However, it's a bit subtle.  This deprecation warning actually *only* applies to the use of the quotation marks in this context, not the column-alias-first format.  I.E., this will be deprecated:

```
'AliasName' = NewValue
```

However, this is still valid and even listed as a replacement for it:

```
AliasName = NewValue
```

So just take the apostrophes out and you're good.

Answer (score 3):

I typically see this syntax when using a subquery to set a variable, @MyValue = (subquery) for example.  So there was a bit of a WTF from me for a minute as well.  However, I see your point, and overall I can't imagine that it is something that would be not supported in the future.

Personally though I prefer a more formatted manner, and a distinct "AS" definition.  I would write it something like this.

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT Lastname + ', ' + Firstname 
     FROM Cust 
     WHERE CustID = O.CustID
    ) AS CustName,
    (SELECT ProductName 
     FROM Product 
     WHERE ProductID = O.ProductID
    ) AS ProdName
FROM Orders O
```

I personally find this easier to read....but more than likely that is just me...

Comment: It's a simplistic example to be sure; the actual production case has about thirty columns in the SELECT statement and I find that putting the column name -- new or original name -- all the way to the left in in the same column of the editor to increase readability. The "WTF" only comes when someone is looking for the column names at the END of the column line (esp on a complex, mnay-line CASE statement) as opposed to being at the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with the

```
column alias = expression
```

syntax and it isn't deemed to be either deprecated soon or bad practice!

The main problem with the query, is that you should be using joins to connect the Orders table to the Cust and Product tables.  The query looks like you are assuming there is only one Customer and one Product per order - think about what would happen if that wasn't true....

```
SELECT 
     'CustName' = C.Lastname + ', ' + C.Firstname,
     'ProdName' = P.ProductName 
FROM Orders O 
JOIN Cust C on C.CustID = O.CustID 
JOIN Product P on P.ProductID= O.ProductID
```

Comment: I had basically the same thing typed up, but you beat me to it.  IMO, the WTF is the subqueries in the select clause.

Comment: the point of my question has nothing to do with how the data is obtained, but about the aliasing syntax

Answer (score 0):

You are aliasing a column name in a strange, unfamiliar way. i had to run it to see if it was even valid.

Rather than doing what's strange and uncommon, do what people expect:

```
SELECT 
   (SELECT Lastname + ', ' + Firstname FROM Cust WHERE CustID = O.CustID) AS CustName,
   (SELECT ProductName FROM Product WHERE ProductID = O.ProductID) AS ProdName
FROM Orders O
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is people balk at it because it's specific to MSSQL, not supported by other systems (at least, not the ones I have available to me right now).  It's like listening to an unfamiliar dialect - you can see what the person is getting at, but you can't see why on Earth they would choose to speak that way.

Comment: Exactly. As a fluent "speaker" of SQL, I just can't see the point of Linq2Sql, for the same reason (though Linq2* looks really useful...).