# SQL Server 2005 error when grouping using subquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, subquery, group-by

Using SQL Server 2005 I'm trying to group based on a case statement with a subquery, but I'm getting an error ("Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column reference.
"). I can work round it quite easily, but can anyone explain the error? I've got a column reference to #header.header.

```
create table #header (header int)
create table #detail (header int, detail int)

insert into #header values (1)
insert into #header values (2)
insert into #header values (3)

insert into #detail values (1, 1)
insert into #detail values (2, 1)

--error: Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column reference.
select case when exists (select 1 from #detail where #detail.header = #header.header) then 1 else 0 end hasrecords from #header
group by case when exists (select 1 from #detail where #detail.header = #header.header) then 1 else 0 end

--results I want
select hasrecords, count(*) from
(
    select case when exists (select 1 from #detail where #detail.header = #header.header) then 1 else 0 end hasrecords from #header
) hasrecords
group by hasrecords

drop table #header
drop table #detail
```

[edit] Note (in response to comment) correlated and non-correlated subqueries:

```
--correlated
select header, case when exists (select 1 from #detail where #detail.header = #header.header) then 1 else 0 end hasrecords from #header

--non-correlated
select #header.header, case when count(#detail.header) > 0 then 1 else 0 end hasrecords from #header left join #detail on #header.header = #detail.header group by #header.header
```

Comment: Grouping by 1 and 0 isn't the problem:

select case when header=1 then 1 else 0 end headeris1, count(*) from #header group by case when header=1 then 1 else 0 end

It's the exist that's causing it, but I don't see why it should. The (silly) rewriting below errors: a subquery can't be used in a group by expression.

select case when 1=(select top 1 header from #header b where b.header = a.header) then 1 else 0 end headeris1, count(*) from #header a group by case when 1=(select top 1 header from #header b where b.header = a.header) then 1 else 0 end

Why can't I use a subquery in a group by?

Comment: The real question is why on earth are you using correlated subqueries at all, ever? They can be performance killers and joins will usually work better so why not start by using joins and only use a correlated subquery if you cant get a join to work (I have never seen an instance of this, your mileage may vary). As a rule when there are multiple ways to do something, you should never start with the one that performs the worst.

Comment: I used correlated subqueries because this seemed to logically reflect what I want to do best - for each header see if there are any records that exist, and not worry how many there are. I'm not clear why correlated subqueries would necessarily perform worse. As a test I added a couple of queries at the bottom of my question. Looking at the execution plans, the one with the join has a query cost of 73% compared to the correlated subquery with query cost 27%. The exists saves a table scan on #detail. I could be wrong, but it seems in this example the correlated subquery performs better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start, if we give the full error, it should read "**Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.**"

To understand the error, we need to clarify what is meant by an **'outer reference'**

(Note: in this case it has nothing to do with inner or outer joins)

The *inner* and *outer* are in reference to the main query and it's subqueries. 
In this case the `EXISTS` is the subquery and it is a ***correlated*** subquery as it has an outer reference of `#header.header`, which is referencing the outer table `#header`, whereas any reference to `#detail` would be considered as inner references.

So in essence, because the `CASE` utilises a correlated subquery that references the outer query, then this fires the error state, beacuse this error message appears when you try to use only expressions in a GROUP BY clause that are interpreted as outer references.

Subqueries **can** be used in GROUP BY, but not correlated subqueries.

Confusingly, the same error can be generated by a non-subqueried, simpler query such as

```
select 
 case when header=1 then 1 
      else 0 
 end headeris1, 
 'constant' 
from #header 
group by case when header=1 then 1 else 0 end , 'constant'
```

or even replacing the constant with a `@variable`

Clear as mud?

Kev

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'm pretty clear now as to why we're getting the error. What I still don't understand is why you can't use correlated subqueries in an group by expression.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling it to group by 1 or 0 when you need to give it an actual column to group by (header), not value.

So if I'm understanding right you are wanting a list of the headers and a count of their detail records?

This may work for you?

```
SELECT DISTINCT h.header, COUNT(d.detail) AS detail_count
FROM #header AS h
LEFT JOIN #detail AS d ON d.header = h.header
GROUP BY h.header, d.detail
```

With results like...

```
header   detail_count
1       1
2       1
3       0
```

Comment: Yup that would work to get the results I'm after, and is probably a neater way to do it then my one.

But this question is specifically why I get the error message, not how to rewrite the query.