# Dupe: Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am getting the following errors when I am trying to create the following stored procedure.

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spReport

    @rLevel nvarchar(50),
    @aSelected nvarchar(64),
    @wType nvarchar(20),
    @dSelected nvarchar(20),
    @StartDate smalldatetime,
    @EndDate smalldatetime

AS
BEGIN


    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @total float 

    if (@dSelected = null)
    begin
        select @total = sum(total) from bs where @rLevel =  CHAR(39)+ @aSelected+CHAR(39) 
                 and wtype = '' + @wType + '' and bdate between CHAR(39)+@StartDate+CHAR(39) and CHAR(39)+@EndDate+CHAR(39) 

        select @rLevel, bdays, str(sum(total*100/@total ),38,2) as percentages, sum(total)as total1 
        from bs 
        where @rLevel= CHAR(39)+@aSelected+CHAR(39) and wtype = CHAR(39)+@wType+CHAR(39) and 
        bdate between CHAR(39)+@StartDate+CHAR(39) and  CHAR(39)+@EndDate+CHAR(39)
        group by @rLevel, bdays 
        order by  
        CASE @rLevel
            WHEN 'r' THEN r
            WHEN 'D' THEN D 
            WHEN 'S' THEN S             
        END
        ,bdays

    end
END
```

Error:
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

I did not understand what I did wrong.

Other than this I am having problem in using the single quotes, Is the way I am using it is it correct?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Each+GROUP+BY+expression+must+contain+at+least+one+column+that+is+not+an+outer+reference, and learn to search.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2005 error when grouping using subquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007418/sql-server-2005-error-when-grouping-using-subquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just don't need to group by a constant expression, and `@rLevel` is one.

So, when you remove it... you'll get another problem. It's your `ORDER BY` clause. It contains references to columns that are neither aggregated nor included in `GROUP BY`. (You can't order by an arbitrary column when you've got a `GROUP BY` clause in your statement.)